# Displaying Coupon Code Messages in a Popup

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, notice

I am trying to display the WooCommerce Coupon messages ("Coupon code applied Successfully" & "Coupon Code does not Exist") in a popup via the plugin [Popups for WooCommerce: Add to Cart, Checkout & More](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-notices-for-woocommerce/) **Pro paid version**. Even though it is a paid plugin, I am getting no support.

[Their documentation](https://wpfactory.com/docs/popup-notices-for-woocommerce/) states any alert can be shown via the following:

> You can use the `[ttt_pnwc_get_message]` shortcode to get dynamic messages from any filter you wish. e.g.
>
> ```
> [ttt_pnwc_get_message filter="wc_add_to_cart_message_html"]
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_error', 'coupon_error_message_change', 10, 3);

function coupon_error_message_change($err, $err_code, $parm) {
    switch ($err_code) {
        case 105:
            /* translators: %s: coupon code */
            $err = sprintf(__('Coupon "%s" does not exist!', 'woocommerce'), $parm->get_code());

            // Using the message in a popup
            $dynamic_message = esc_html($err);
            
            // Display the dynamic message in the popup using the shortcode
            echo do_shortcode("[ttt_pnwc_get_message message='$dynamic_message']");
            break;
    }
    return $err;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to accomplish this without the pluign? The idea is to display woocommerce notices in a popup rather than the traditional info bar.

Comment: I found this from the developer: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 ttt_pnwc.clearPopupMessages();
 ttt_pnwc.messages.push({message: 'Message 1', type: 'success'});
 ttt_pnwc.messages.push({message: 'Message 2', type: 'error'});
 ttt_pnwc.messages.push({message: 'Message 3', type: 'info'}); 
 ttt_pnwc.addMessagesToPopup();
 ttt_pnwc.openPopup();
});    Any ideas how this could be utilized?